# Quelle est la différence de prononciation entre « au-dessous » et « au-dessus » ?

Tags: prononciation, indications-de-lieu

J'ai toujours du mal à me faire comprendre quand il me faut expliquer où j'habite. Je veux dire :

> J'habite le hameau au-dessous de Les Onchets.

Mais mon interlocuteur comprend :

> *I live in the hamlet **above** Les Onchets.*

Qu'est-ce que je peux faire pour être sûr que l'autre personne me comprenne ? Comment m'entraîner à prononcer correctement *Au-dessous* /odəsy/ et *Au-dessus* /odəsu/ ?

Apologies for my terrible French—this is the first question I have attempted to write in French!  In case I am not making myself clear, I am looking for a way to pronounce *au-dessous* vs *au-dessus* so that I can make myself clearly understood.

While I think about it.  If I was talking about wearing an item of clothing underneath (or above) another item, would *au-dessous*/​*au-dessus* be appropriate here too?

Comment: Upvoted because you tried, despite difficulty, to pose your question in French :)

Comment: Hehe, merci @Brennan :)

Comment: Il est moins gênant de confondre dessus/dessous que cou et cul... :)

Comment: If your native language is English, it's pretty surprising that people understand /y/ when you mean /u/ rather than the converse. The French /u/ is just like the English /u:/ in "boot", just shorter, whereas the /y/ does not occur in English and is notoriously difficult for English speakers to make. If you need to practice your /y/, *don't* work from /u:/. Instead, work from /iː/ (e.g., in "free"), and try to change it to /y/ by moving your lips to a rounded position <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roundedness> and by *not* moving your tongue or anything else.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

À part accentuer la différence entre la prononciation des sons [y] et [u] (ce qui n'est pas toujours facile pour un non-francophone), une autre façon pourrait être d'utiliser la forme `en dessous de`.

Il n'existe pas de forme "en **dessus** de", et par conséquent, il est plus facile pour un francophone d'identifier immédiatement la différence entre `au dessus` et `en dessous` (grâce au "au"/"en" qui précède):

> J'habite au hameau en dessous de Les Onchets

Peut-être justement à cause de ce risque de confusion, je dirais que la forme "en dessous" est souvent préférée à "au-dessous", particulièrement lorsque suivi de "de".

À noter qu'un simple `sous` est aussi parfaitement correct (théoriquement moins soutenu, mais dans la pratique pas moins utilisé):

> J'habite au hameau [qui se trouve] sous Les Onchets

... avec l'avantage d'éviter le "de Les" disharmonieux (dont je me demande en fait s'il ne doit/peut pas être contracté... je crois que je vais poser la question moi-même ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend this video [The French vowels /y/ and /u/ with explanations in English](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4XFrRnCOvM&list=UU2L9w7ozDeUl1w5ZjUPCOQA&index=15&feature=plcp). Maybe you're just confusing the sounds as you did in your question? :) *au-dessous* is /odəsu/ and *au-dessus* is /odəsy/ - not the other way round. Good luck with French vowels!

Comment: Actually we never say "au dessous", but always "en dessous". Similarly we don't say "en dessus" but always "au dessus". This is helpful to understand and to be understood as "au"/"en" is not ambiguous.

Comment: Oh my... Of course! But isn't "au-dessus" written with a hyphen?

Comment: Yes, *au-dessus* has an hyphen, but not *en dessous*(http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dessous). And my comment is not accurate actually: au-dessous, en-dessus do exist, but are (way) less common and have a slightly different meaning.