# Contraction de « de Les », « de La » ou « de Le » dans les noms propres

Tags: articles, noms-propres, contractions

En lisant cette phrase (tirée de [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/313/comment-on-prononce-au-dessous-vs-au-dessus)) :

> J'habite au hameau en dessous de Les Onchets.

Ma *Sprachgefühl* est quelque peu heurtée par la non-contraction de « de Les » et je me demandais s'il s'agit d'un cas typique de français où la version plus euphonique est moins correcte (un peu comme l'indicatif après « après que »), ou s'il était autorisé (voire indiqué) de contracter l'article dans un tel cas…

Il me semble qu'en général on ne fasse pas la contraction avec les noms propres, existerait-il une exception à l'exception pour les toponymes (j'imagine que « Les Onchets » est un nom de village) ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Mon premier réflexe de locuteur natif me dit qu'on fait toujours la contraction, pour les noms propres comme pour les noms communs, sauf lorsqu'il s'agit d'une personne. Quand je vois « de Le ___ » ou « de Les ___ » s'agissant d'un nom de lieu, j'ai tendance à penser à un nom étranger (italien ou espagnol). Ceci vaut aussi bien pour la préposition « à » que pour « de ».

Le Havre → du Havre (et non <strike>de Le Havre</strike>)
Le Mans → du Mans (et non <strike>de Le Mans</strike>)
Les Aubrais → des Aubrais (et non <strike>de Les Aubrais</strike>)
Les Ulis → des Ulis (et non <strike>de Les Ulis</strike>)
lire *les Misérables* → lecture des *Misérables* (et non <strike>lecture de *les Misérables*</strike>)
lire *le Monde* → lecture du *Monde*  (et non <strike>lecture de *le Monde*</strike>)

Pour chacun de ces six exemples, j'ai fait des recherches sur [google.fr](http://www.google.fr/) de `"de le Havre"` et `"du Havre"`, etc. Dans chaque cas, les usages de « de le » ou « de les » dans les 20 premiers résultats sont très majoritairement de deux types :

- des pages web générées automatiquement à partir d'une base de données (liste des agences immobilières de `<ville>`, fiche de lecture de `<titre>`, ...) ;
- des noms composés, pour lequel la préposition qualifie plus que le nom propre qui commence par un article : « aéroport de Le Havre-Octeville », « gare de Les Aubrais-Orléans », « élargissement de Le Mans Métropole¹ ».

Dans ce dernier cas, l'usage n'est pas systématique ; je dirais que la contraction est majoritaire mais je n'ai pas du tout cherché à faire des statistiques précises.

J'en conclus que mon usage est celui d'une large majorité de locuteurs français (au moins des francophones de France, je ne sais pas si l'usage est différent dans d'autres pays francophone).

Pour un nom de personne, la contraction me choque, et une recherche Google comme précédemment montre qu'elle est ultraminoritaire.

Le Clézio → de Le Clézio (et non <strike>du Clézio</strike>)
Le Corbusier → de Le Corbusier (et non <strike>du Corbusier</strike>)

¹  <sub>Dont je trouve l'orthographe curieuse, au passage : pourquoi une majuscule² à « métropole » ?</sub> 
²  <sub>Oui, je sais, une capitale, si ça vous fait plaisir.</sub>

Comment: Merci pour cette réponse exhaustive... C'est donc plus ou moins ce qu'il me semblait intuitivement: on ne contracte pas, sauf pour les toponymes (ou dit autrement: "on contracte, sauf pour les noms de personnes"?). Je serais curieux de savoir si cela est clairement énoncé en tant que règle quelque part...

Comment: @Dave Je pense que la règle est qu'on contracte, sauf pour les noms de personnes. On ne contracte ni les toponymes, ni les titres, ni je pense les autres noms propres (il n'y en a pas des masses, et aucun qui commence par un article ne me vient à l'esprit). Il faudrait quand même vérifier dans une grammaire pour avoir un autre point de vue.

Comment: Le Mans Métropole est un nom de lieu donc la majuscule est logique pour moi. http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Mans_M%C3%A9tropole

Comment: Non, Le Mans Métropole est une structure, pas un lieu. Mais le mot métropole est inclus dans le nom de cette structure : il s'agit d'un nom propre, ce qui justifie également à mes yeux l'usage de la majuscule.

Comment: Je ne suis pas étonné que les statistiques montrent la préférence de la contraction, mais je me demande ce qu'en disent les autorités de la langue française. Pour ma part je fais la contraction, mais ça m'embête toujours un peu, je trouve ça "pas logique".

Answer (score 4):

La plupart du temps, on remplace "de Les" par "des", même dans les noms propres, mais ce n'est pas toujours le cas. Cependant, cet usage est considéré comme plus standard. Par exemple:

> J'habite au Mans
>   Je n'ai lu que le premier tome des *Misérables*

Answer (score 3):

Exemple Belge:

Dans le cas de [la ville du Roeulx](http://www.leroeulx.be), l'usage le plus courant est de faire la contraction, comme en témoigne le site officiel: *Ville du Roeulx*, *Prochainement au Roeulx*, *[centre culturel du Roeulx](http://www.leroeulxculture.be/)*... Quand j'ai entendu parler de la ville la première fois, j'avais tendance à ne pas le faire, mais je ne pense pas avoir entendu qui que ce soit d'autre dire *la ville de Le Roeulx*.

Sur un registre plus connu, ne parle-t-on pas des *vingt-quatre heures **du** Mans*?

Answer (score 2):

Je ne crois pas que la *non-contraction* soit la norme. Souvent, la méthode pour résoudre ce problème est de contracter *de* et *le*, et ensuite de mettre en italique le nom pour indiquer que c'est un nom propre. Par exemple, on voit souvent dans le journal *Le Monde* une telle chose :

> Dans un article précédent du *Monde*, il a dit que...

Answer (score 2):

J'habite la ville des Vans en Ardèche. Dans la conversation courante, on dit généralement : je suis aux Vans, je viens des Vans etc. Malheureusement, dans les documents écrits, sur des panneaux et même en mairie, il est question de Ville de Les Vans, ce qui heurte profondément mon sens de la grammaire. On me répond généralement que c'est la norme dans les documents officiels. Je n'en suis pas si sûr mais je n'ai jamais vu de papiers officiels des villes du Mans ou du Havre. A suivre...

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour,
Je crois que la contraction doit se faire si l'article défini est masculin.
https://www.dictionnaire-academie.fr/article/QDL058
Cette faute est apparue, je pense, avec les formulaires pré-remplis.

Comment: Et pour le pluriel ?

Answer (score 1):

Moi, j'habite un petit village qui s'appelle *« Les Baroches »* et je dis toujours que j'habite à *« Les Baroches. »*
Je corrige quand quelqu'un me demande si je viens « des Baroches .»
Je ne vis pas à « Baroches » mais à « Les Baroches ! »

Comment: Je dirais *reprendre* plutôt que *corriger* car ça semble un usage très local. Il n'y a peut-être que *des Les Barochois* qui le disent...

Comment: Voire une seule Les Barochoise ? D'ailleurs, est-ce que tu dis je suis *Barochoise* ou je suis *Les Barochoise* ?