# Des « le journal de Mickey » ou des « journaux de Mickey »

Tags: usage, articles, pluriel, noms-propres

Petit, je lisais le magazine « le journal de Mickey ». Dois-je dire que j'ai lu des « le journal de Mickey » ou des « journaux de Mickey »?

Nous pouvons bien entendu faire en sorte de construire notre phrase pour éviter ces formulations étranges mais ce n'est pas ma question.

Un autre exemple :

- J'ai une pile de « Figaro » ou de « Le Figaro » au pied de mon chevet.

Il est naturel d'utiliser la première formulation mais est-ce correct ?

Comment: De mon côté, je lisais des Mickey... tout bêtement.

Comment: Une excellente question que je me suis posée mille fois en tant que locuteur natif, donc effectivement ce n'est pas clairement établi, je suis curieux de voir les réponses.

Comment: On ne dirait j'ai lu *Les Mondes* mais j'ai lu [des numéros de] *Le Monde*.

Comment: Question similaire en ce qui concerne la contraction : https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/315/contraction-de-de-les-de-la-ou-de-le-dans-les-noms-propres

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ni l'un ni l'autre tel qu'écrit. [*Le Journal de Mickey*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Journal_de_Mickey) est un [magazine](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8366321) (voir [*périodique*](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3223), [*publication en série*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2069115); on peut parler d'un [*numéro*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8364896) ou d'un [*exemplaire*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=2069277).); l'article fait partie du titre ici.  [Généralement](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=2664)<sup>1</sup>, l'article, dans ce cas, prend la majuscule, ainsi que le premier nom et les noms propres; si on contracte l'article du titre avec « *à* » ou « *de* », on ne le met pas en majuscule. Le titre est écrit en *italique*, ou entre guillemets en contexte manuscrit uniquement.

> Le magazine *Le Journal de Mickey*.
>  C'est tiré du *Journal de
>   Mickey*.

L'emploi *métonymique*. Si *Mickey* produisait lui-même le magazine et que tous étaient familiers avec son œuvre, on pourrait sans doute en parler avec le nom seul au pluriel (des *Mickeys*, en plus du [singulier](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/14003/des-le-journal-de-mickey-ou-des-journaux-de-mickey#comment26457_14003)), le cas échéant. Le titre autrement est souvent invariable (« Dix-huit mille [*Baiser au lépreux*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Baiser_au_l%C3%A9preux) tirés. » (Mauriac, *Journal d'un homme de trente ans*, 16 mai 1922; voir sur l'[accord des verbes](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=3125)); mais pas toujours (« [...] vingt *Iliades*. » (R Rolland, *Jean-Chr.*, t. V, p. 45), et « surtout pour les revues et les collections » : « Je feuilletais des vieux [*Magasins Pittoresques*](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Magasin_pittoresque) » (Mauriac, *Robe prétexte*, XXIX).— *Le bon usage*, ed. Boeck et Duculot, §525. Ma remarque serait que dans bien des cas, il s'agit d'ajouter un « s » alors qu'ici le pluriel est *journaux* et on s'écarte donc du nom formel du magazine. Mais on est libre d'utiliser le « des ***J***ournaux de Mickey », semble-t-il, en plus du « [des ***J***ournal de Mickey](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14005) », et de l'emploi avec [*numéro(s)*](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14004) que d'autres réponses suggèrent.

---

<sub>1. Cette façon de faire et son application aux [oeuvres et ouvrages](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?th=2&id=1497) n'est peut-être pas normalisée dans l'ensemble de la francophonie; il faudra comparer avec les règles traditionnelles, le cas échéant.</sub>

Answer (score 8):

Pour commencer, les titres de livres et de périodiques ne prennent pas la marque du pluriel.

Personnellement, j'aurais tendance à dire *des journal de Mickey*, mais la formulation de Random avec *des numéros du* ou *des copies du* est également très naturelle et probablement la moins à risque d'attirer les foudres d'un grammairien du dimanche.

Answer (score 7):

Je pense que les deux sonnent mal. Je tournerais plutôt la phrase comme suit :

> Je lisais le journal de Mickey.

qui est assez explicite sur le fait qu'on ait lu plusieurs numéros, grâce à l'utilisation de l'imparfait.

Si on veut *vraiment* utiliser le passé composé (qui ne parle donc pas d'une habitude mais d'un moment particulier), on pourrait dire :

> J'ai lu des numéros du journal de Mickey.

Answer (score 2):

Je lisais «le Journal de Mickey».

J'ai lu quelques numéros du «Journal de Mickey». Ceci est la bonne formulation.

Je lisais «les journaux de Mickey» voudrait dire que je lisais les journaux qui appartenaient à Mickey.