# Contractions « de le(s) », noms d'œuvres et typographie

Tags: noms-propres, contractions, titres

Une convention typographique oblige à écrire les noms des œuvres (livres, films, etc.) en italique. Néanmoins lors d'une contraction entre « de » et « le(s) », par exemple, je n'ai pas trouvé quelles sont les règles précises à appliquer.

Par exemple la phrase :

> Une lecture des Misérables

Met-on le déterminant « des » en majuscule comme on l'aurait fait pour le déterminant « Les » dans « Les Misérables » ? Et que met-on en italique : *des Misérables* ou uniquement *Misérables* ?

Comment: Vous pouvez regarder [cette réponse](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/324/7321). En toute logique, l'italique devrait respecter la même règle que les majuscules...

Comment: @Random J'ai effectivement examiné cette question et les réponses qui y ont été fournies avant d'écrire ma propre question, mais les réponses ne précisent pas réellement l'aspect typographique dont je parle et passent dessus sans vraiment expliquer le pourquoi du comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Une lecture des *Misérables*.

S'il y a contraction avec les prépositions *à* ou *de* qui précèdent, on ne met en italiques (et incidemment en majuscule la première lettre du premier mot) que ce qui appartient au titre de livre original ([Termium](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/redac-chap?lang=eng&lettr=chapsect5&info0=5.2.1), [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1497), LBU14 §101d, R7). Mais ce peut être bien plus compliqué et on peut approfondir la réflexion en lisant la discussion sur [orthotypograhie.fr](http://www.orthotypographie.fr/volume-II/telegramme-troncation.html) à l'entrée *titre d’œuvre* ; on a l'exemple « il a lu cent fois le dernier chapitre des *Misérables* ». La question de la [majuscule](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/14008) avec l'article au titre, a fortiori selon qu'il est défini ou indéfini, déborde du cadre de la question et l'usage varie. Et il faut noter qu'il y a aussi variété relativement au choix de contracter ou non, et on (§580 b 2°) dit qu'il y a *le plus souvent* contraction dans un cas comme celui qu'on présente, alors qu'on distingue encore, selon que le titre contienne un nom composé avec coordination avec *et/ou* ; et dans ce cas l'usage veut qu'on contracte ou non, plus librement. Grevisse et Goosse semblent préférer (au LBU14) l'emploi d'un terme générique (*roman*, etc.) afin de pouvoir simplement juxtaposer le titre sans altération. Il s'agit d'un bref survol et il y a d'autres nuances...