# Les contractions devant le titre de quelque chose?

Tags: grammaire, contractions, de

Par exemple, un de mes profs a dit « On va lire un passage qui vient des Misérables par Victor Hugo ».

Ne faut-il pas dire « qui vient *de Les* Misérables par Victor Hugo » car on parle du titre d'une œuvre ?

Même chose pour Le Petit Prince, Le Petit Nicolas, etc.

Comment: Ton prof a raison : les déterminants dans les titres se combinent. D'ailleurs, n'oublie pas que seulement la première lettre est en majuscule : "Il a parlé du *Petit prince*."

Comment: Voir aussi [ici](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/12835/3177), [là](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/14003/3177), et [là](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/315/3177)... Merci !

Answer (score 3):

Les contractions s'appliquent aussi aux titres, noms de sites, mais pas noms de personnes:

- je viens du Touquet (et non de "le Touquet");
- je vais au Touquet (et non à "le Touquer");
- j'ai lu la traduction du Prince (et non de "le Prince");
- je pense au Dernier Métro (et non à "le Dernier Métro").

mais
- j'apprécie l'interprétation des *Le Quesnoy* (dans "la vie est un long fleuve tranquille").