# Do we say "je vais à Les Angles" or "je vais aux Angles" ?

Tags: prépositions, noms-propres

I learnt that in French, "à les" is contracted to "aux." But I also learnt that we don't alter a proper name. So the name of the ski resort is "Les Angles"... So ... must we say "Je vais à Les Angles" or "Je vais aux Angles" ?

Comment: Not a complete duplicate, but very much related.

Comment: Actual duplicate: https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/315/contraction-de-de-les-de-la-ou-de-le-dans-les-noms-propres

Answer (score 1):

Il faut absolument faire la contraction :

> Je vais aux Angles.

Tout comme :

- Je vais **aux** États unis.
- Je vais **aux** Bahamas.

Comment: L'exemple avec le Canada n'est pas relevant ici...

Comment: @LaurentS. Pertinent *even* ;-)

Comment: Effectivement, à force de parler anglais au boulot je fais des anglicisme sans même m'en rendre compte...